# Combinatorics: Singular Inversion Theorem vs Smooth Implicit-Function Schema

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, power-series

In lecture I saw the following theorem:

> **Singular Inversion Theorem**: Let $\phi(u)$ be analytic at $0$ and its series expansion $\phi(u) = \sum_{k} \phi_k u^k$ at $0$ satisfy the following conditions:
>
> 1. $\phi(0) \ne 0$
> 2. $[u^k]\phi(u) \ge 0 \quad (\forall k \ge 0)$
> 3. $[u^k]\phi(u) > 0  \text{ for some } k \ge 0$, i.e $\phi(u)$ is non-linear
> 4. The radius of convergence of $\sum_k \phi_k u^k$ is $R \in (0, \infty]$.
>
> If there exists a unique solution $u_0 \in (0,R)$ of the equation
> $$\phi(u) - u\phi^\prime(u) = 0, $$
> then the solution $u(z)$ of the equation $u(z) = z\phi(u(z))$ satisfies the following:
>
> 1. $u(z)$ is analytic at $0$
> 2. The dominant singularity of $u(z)$ is given by $\rho := \frac{u_0}{\phi(u_0)}$.
> 3. The singular expansion of $u(z)$ for $z \rightarrow \rho$ is of the form
>    $$u(z) = u_0 - \sqrt{ \frac{2 \phi(u_0)}{ \phi^{\prime\prime}(u_0) }} \biggl( 1- \frac{z}{\rho} \biggr)^{1/2} + \sum_{j \ge 2} C_j \biggl(1 + \frac{z}{\rho} \biggr)^{j/2}$$
> 4. If additionally $\phi$ is aperiodic, then
>    $$ [z^n]u(z) = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{ \phi(u_0)}{ \phi^{\prime\prime} }} n^{-3/2} \rho^{-n} \cdot \bigg(1 + \mathcal{O}\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg)\bigg).$$
>    **Remark**: Apparently this is a variant of the Singular Inversion Theorem described in Flajolet & Sedgewick p.404)

It was said that for a generating function $A(z)$ and $\phi$ a power series, as above, with $A(z) = z \phi(A(z))$ and $G(z,w) := z \phi(w)$ the condition of this theorem are *equivalent* to the conditions for the Smooth Implicit Function Schema (as described in Flajolet & Sedgewick p.467, 468; see pictures below).

I do not see why this should be the case:

First of all I think that the condition $u_0 = 0$ contradicts the condition $\phi(0) \ne 0$.

Then I do not see how the characteristic system from the Smooth Implicit-Function Schema relates to conditions 1) to 3) in the Singular Inversion Theorem.  I realise that they are similar, but I do not see how $\phi$ is related to $G$.

On another note, I do not really see the difference between the asymptotic estimations of $[z^n]u(z)$ and $[z^n]y(z)$ given in the two theorems.

Could you please explain this to me?

[image]
[image]